# Is the short-e pronounced as [e] or [ɛ] in standard English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, ipa

In many English dictionaries, I saw the phonetic symbol of short-e is /e/ such as in *bed* (/bed/). However, I'm taught that the pronunciation of that is /ɛ/. Which one is right in standard English? Does such a difference exist for native speakers?

This question is very different from [Could you clarify /e/ and /ɛ/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304334) because I can very clearly understand the difference between /e/ and /ɛ/ in my mother tongue. I am asking which one is correct in standard English, and what's the native speakers' suggestion to English learners on these two sounds.

Comment: To people who care about such things, there's a slight difference in ***sound*** between the two vowels represented by [ɛ] and [e]. But I think I'm right in saying that most native speakers wouldn't really recognise any distinction - any given speaker would normally use only ***one*** version himself, but there's no "minimal pair" of different words that are distinguished by which of those two vowels are used. So really it's no more significant than the fact that (on average) ***she*** will articulate "the" phoneme in a higher pitch than ***he*** will.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Thanks, but I'm not asking how to clarify them apart. What I what to know is how English native speakers pronounce the short-e, or to say, what's the right pronunciation in standarad English.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard"?  Pronunciation of vowels varies considerably between countries. Could you tie it down to a particular area?  Here is a pronunciation dictionary that allows you to hear various accents (click the LISTEN button). There are seven different ones for "bed"!  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/bed

Comment: @PeterShor You can't treat [ɛ] and [e] as allophones since they have to be allophones of something; they are rather standards of sound that have allophones and it might be said that some allophones of the first are quite similar to allophones of the second, to the point even of not knowing which is which. I must mention my personal experience as I have got for the vowel in "bed" the American vowel (south) which is definitely [ɛ] and that I internalized; I still have it in spite of some training in RP and I can contrast it clearly with traditional English English [e]  (1/2)

Comment: @PeterShor in its ideal form, that one being close to the French é. I is true that this ideal vowel is disappearing in British English (even in RP, which, let's recall that, a good twenty years ago wasn't spoken by much more than 3 % of the British population) but it isn't yet "dead and buried" and Wells' symbols are a testimony to that. I think the distinction has to be preserved for the time being, until at least when  the time comes for a contemporary leading figure in this domain  (such as J.C. Wells) to judge necessary to  forget about it. (2/2)

Comment: @PeterShor Here is for instance this ideal [e] vowel in the word "get" in a Rolling Stone song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv9sDn_2XkI

Comment: @LPH: Are you sure that the Rolling Stones aren't using a common variant American pronunciation of get — /gɪt/? The Rolling stones use a lot of Americanisms, and it definitely sounds like *git* to me. (Although it's non-standard, lots of Americans pronounce *get* as *git*, and in some regions, it's pretty much standard, although this phoneme change doesn't extend to bet, let, met, pet, wet, etc.)

Comment: @PeterShor Those two can be very close, but from what I know of Jagger's English (off stage) it is quite faithful to RP. Nevertheless, it is still possible that I do not hear this "get" properly, I wouldn't swear by it.

Comment: @LPH: Offstage, I agree that Jagger uses RP.  When I said they used a lot of Americanisms, I was talking about in their songs. (e.g., *I'm just waiting on a friend*.)

Comment: @PeterShor It would be nice to have more people voicing their opinion so as to let us know what they hear in this song.

Comment: @LPH: Mick Jagger is singing git. [Here](https://blog.oup.com/2015/09/sir-david-willcocks-remembered/) is a web page that mentions how Mick Jagger had to explain to the London Bach choir that they shouldn't use the posh pronunciation of "You can't always get what you want", but that it should be more like "‘Yer kannt always git wot yer whannt". (But it doesn't seem to me to have been entirely successful; in the song, that line in the first verse still sounds a lot more posh to me than when Mick Jagger sings it.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know why you say those two phonemes sound nearly alike. If you listen to [the Queen’s Speech from today](https://youtu.be/aJTw3Alni_Y), to my ears she very clearly distinguishes /ɛ/ from /e/. Listen closely to her stressed vowels in *a fɛstive mood, around his rɛsting place, Unknown Warrior was not excɛptional, a symbol of sɛlfless duty, spirit of sɛlflessness.*

Comment: @tchrist I believe "selfless", "resting" and so on are pronounced with /e/, the particular allophone used being however quite close to an allophone of /ɛ/; this can be inferred from a listen to the contiguous e and a of "celebrated" (1' 29''),  in which the first sound of the diphthong for a, rendered by "/eɪ/" in Longman Pronunciation dictionary  is usually reckoned to be not the allophone used in "get" but an allophone nearer to /ɛ/.

Comment: @LPH I genuinely believe your notation to be in error or dated. The Queen 
is pronouncing *selfless, resting,* etc with the /ɛ/ vowel of DRESS—just as 
the OED gives for those words: they show [*selfless* as
/ˈsɛlfləs/](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175323) and [*restless* as
/ˈrɛs(t)ləs/](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/163975). Please also observe how
Britain and Ireland have no /e/ in words like
[*red*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/red),
[*head*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/head),
[*ten*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/ten).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which one is standard depends on which variety of English you speak.

In the U.S., the standard pronunciation is [ɛ]. If you say [bɛt], people would understand you to be saying *bet*, while if you say [bet], it might be heard as *bait* (although probably not if the meaning is clear from context).

In the U.K., the standard RP (upper-class) pronunciation used to be [e]. However, despite the fact that dictionaries still represent the phoneme as /e/, this has changed — see [this blog post](https://www.englishspeechservices.com/blog/british-vowels/). Today, they're allophones; as @FumbleFingers says in the comments, both of them would be heard as *bet*, and various people use one or the other.

So when learning English, as a purely practical matter, you should use [ɛ], because that pronunciation will be clearly understood by both Americans and Brits.

Comment: A good number of the pronunciations recorded in that blog are atrocious; it seems that their principle of selection of representative  pronunciations of BrE is founded on an insistence on the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @LPH: whether you think the pronunciations are atrocious or not, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/key-to-pronunciation) has been keeping its pronunciation up to date with common modern standard British pronunciations. And they use /kat/ for *cat*, /bɛd/ for *bed*, /hɛː/ for *hair*, and /kjɔː/ for *cure* (this last one does sound atrocious to my American ears; it should be /kjʊr/, /kjər/, or maybe even /kjuər/).

Comment: Right, RP -ure is /kjʊər/, not far from /kjʊr/ as in diphthongs the second sound is always much less prominent. Would you believe that along with this regular pronunciation of -ure endings, as an exception in RP, "sure" is pronounced "ʃɔː"?

Comment: @LPH: *sure* and *poor* used to be pronounced /ʃʊə/ and /pʊə/ in RP, just like *cure, moor, pure, tour, boor,* and *spoor*. The only difference is that these two words changed their pronunciation to /ʃɔː/ and /pɔː/ in the early 20th century, before you learned English, while the others are changing their pronunciation afterward.

Answer (score 2):

In AmE the pronunciation is rather [ɛ]: /bɛd/; in BrE the traditional pronunciation, considered to be RP by some, is [e]: /bed/. However, in BrE regional variants tend towards [ɛ] or are [ɛ]. This can be verified at [John Wells Phonetic Blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/02/lexical-sets.html).