# The letter "a" pronounced as an "e"

Tags: pronunciation

In the English language there are many words where the letter "a" is pronounced as a short (continental European) "e". Or at least very close to it.

However dictionaries point out that in these cases the correct pronunciation is more an "ae" sound. Several websites on English pronunciation take the same view. So I decided to test this assumption. Over a period of weeks, whenever I watched an English or American television program, I payed attention how these "a"-words where actually pronounced by native English speakers, and made notes of my observations. I found out that in fact there are many words that have the pure "e" sound. A few examples: back, cash, cat, fact, relax, track, crash.

So what is going on here? Are this words pronounced incorrectly, or are the dictionaries and websites promoting viewpoints about pronunciation that are outdated? Or has it to do with regional variations (dialects)?

Comment: Please provide links to examples from the television shows you mentioned. Writing this in IPA would also be helpful.

Comment: (Note also that [æ] is not a diphthong.)

Comment: AFAIK the only British English speakers who pronounce those words with an 'e' sound are speakers of extreme [RP](https://www.bl.uk/british-accents-and-dialects/articles/received-pronunciation) - like the joke about posh people thinking that [sex was what coal came in](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-the-coal-came-in.762136/)

Comment: Once again, it is necessary to remind everyone that (a) English spelling has no regular connection with English pronunciation, and (b) only people make speech sounds; all letters in all English spellings are silent, and are sensible only to the eyes, not the ears, and (c) English grammar and usage refers to **spoken** English. Also, that discussing pronunciation in writing online is a losers' game.

Comment: @ John Lawler I was just about to question whether there is a continental pure 'e'.  I assume the Franco-Belgian 'e' as in 'je' or 'menu' or 'livre' is meant.  But yes, you give a salutory reminder about class, regional and ethnic pronunciation (which are fading in the face of 'Beebish').

Comment: So, you think "track" and "trek" are pronounced the same?  I don't.  Probably your difficulty hearing the difference is because your native language does not have this distinction.

Comment: @Tuffy The written "e" in [French *je*  /ʒə/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/je#Pronunciation_6) is at most an [ə] not an [e]. In [French *livre*  /livʁ/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/livre#Pronunciation_2) it's not even there! For a real [e] look at words like [Spanish *Pepe*  /ˈpepe/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pepe#Pronunciation) or [Spanish *beber* /beˈβ̞eɾ/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beber#Pronunciation_5). Hear the difference? A schwa is not an /e/.

Comment: This question indicates a lack of knowledge in phonetics, which you might alleviate by learning: 1) the phonetic values of some IPA symbols like [a], [æ], and [e]; 2) the total lack of alignment between orthography and pronunciation, especially in English; and 3) the significant variance among vowel systems in European languages.

Comment: @tchrist.  I have zero knowledge of phonetics, I am afraid.  All I am sure is that the letter 'e' in French 'je', or 'menu' rhymes with the letter 'a' in 'material' or 'give a dog a bone'.

Comment: @Tuffy Letters don't rhyme. Sounds do. You’re talking about a schwa. Calling that an "e" just leaves us with nothing to discuss here. You cannot talk about pronunciations using unscientific hand-waving to go spelling out lettered spelling-pronunciations.

Answer (score 4):

> I found out that in fact there are many words that have the pure "e" sound. A few examples: back, cash, cat, fact, relax, track, crash.

No, they do not. The [IPA /e/ sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) does not occur in those words. You have confused it for the [/æ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel) vowel, which does occur in them.

Listen to these Youglish samples for [*fact*](https://youglish.com/pronounce/fact/english?) and for [*relax*](https://youglish.com/pronounce/relax/english?), and try hard to find even one that has an /e/ in it for the given word.  Use the "skip-forwards" button that looks a little like ⏭ to move through the thousands of samples, or the "skip-backwards" button that looks a little like ⏮ to move back through the list. You can do the same with the other words you mention.

Where are you thinking you're hearing these? [Very few regional accents pronounce the vowel of *ash*  /æʃ/ with any kind of an "e" sound](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/ash), although a few do. Are you in one of those regions?

If you do not have all three of [/e/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) and [/ɛ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) and [/æ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel) sounds in your native language as contrasting phonemes, then you may not be hearing them correctly. If so, then you may not be able hear the clear difference between triples like *mate* with /e/, *met* with /ɛ/, and *mat* with /æ/.

Are those three different phonemes for you? What's your first language? I ask so we can look at its phonemic repertoire, the aural lens through which you may tend to hear the world.

You [earlier wrote](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/334461/141):

> For me as a foreigner it is impossible to distinguish the pronunciation of "set" versus "sat". Are native English speakers able to hear a subtle difference between the two?

This shows that you cannot hear those sounds correctly. To us, they are worlds apart, just as *meet* and *mitt* and *met* and *mat* and *mate* all are.

One last thing about dictionaries. They never have real pronunciations. So they will always be inaccurate. That's in part because to a large extent, saying that there is one "American pronunciation" or there is one "British pronunciation" is a myth. Better to look at each region for [*hand*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/hand), [*lamb*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/lamb), [*bath*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/bath). Each of those has **dozens** of different regional pronunciations by native speakers. No dictionary ever covers real pronunciations to this degree of accuracy because it will never help anyone to do so. So the idea that the dictionaries haven't caught up to reality is ill-founded: they never shall.

Comment: One additional note: [in General American](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki//æ/_raising), /æ/ is pronounced as something like [ɛə] before nasals. This may trip up the asker if they try to "hear" the /æ/ sound in a word like "camp" or "hand."

Comment: @alphabet To some extent, GA is a myth. Better to look at each region for [*hand*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/hand), [*lamb*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/lamb), [*bath*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/bath). Each of those has dozens of pronunciations. No dictionary ever covers real pronunciations to this degree of accuracy because it will never help anyone to do so. So the idea that the dictionaries haven't caught up to reality is ill-founded: they never shall.

Comment: Fair enough. General American should really be demoted to Colonel American at this point.

Comment: But aren't /e/ and /ɛ/ allophones in english? Isn't just a difference based on regional accents?

Comment: @tac No, they are completely separate phonemes, **not allophones**. Changing one for the other makes it a completely different word: /mæt/ and /mɛt/ and /met/ are not the same at all: *mat* vs *met* vs *mate*. This is unlike Spanish, which does have /e/ but doesn't have /ɛ/, so any [ɛ] that ever shows up there (it mostly does not, **unless** you're a speaker who drops terminal "s" from a syllable and compensates by opening the vowel remaining there; Andalusians and Carribeans, for example) would be an allophone of /e/. But English does not work that way.

Comment: @tchrist [Look at this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304334/could-you-clarify-e-and-%C9%9B), please. Based on what appears, I don't see any problem if I want to use /e/ and /eI/ for both e's instead of using /ɛ/ and /eI/ or viceversa. Explain, please.

Answer (score 1):

> Over a period of weeks, whenever I watched an English or American television program, I payed attention how these "a"-words where actually pronounced by native English speakers, and made notes of my observations. I found out that in fact there are many words that have the pure "e" sound. A few examples: back, cash, cat, fact, relax, track, crash.

Unfortunately, all this means is that your ears are not attuned to the difference between a pair of vowel sounds that are distinguished in English. Almost all native English speakers use different vowels in the following 2 sets of words:

- *back, cash, cat, fact, relax, track, crash* (set 1)
- *beckon, question, kettle, infection, lecture, trek, thresh* (set 2).

There are different conventions about how to transcribe the vowel in set 1 and set 2, but most often you'll see /æ/ and /ɛ/ respectively. But these are just symbols. It isn't certain that either one is the same as a vowel in your language or another European language, although you might hear them like that. English speakers often have trouble hearing the difference between the vowels in French *roux* and *rue,* or [German "musste" and "müsste"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73480/), or the [German "ee" and "ie" sounds](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/problem-differentiating-between-i-and-e), but French speakers and German speakers find it easy to hear the difference in their own languages.

Comment: Indeed, native German speakers regularly merge the *mat* vowel into the *met* vowel when adopting English loanwords per [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology). It's not 100% clear to me what happens with all Dutch speakers or all Russian speakers on this front, but there might be some of that there, too.

Comment: @tchrist: I have definitely read some things by Russian speakers who say they hear this vowel pair as the same.

Comment: Gordon Ramsay said: "Ladies and gentlemen, we are closing the restaurant. Please come BACK in 24 hours when we reopen." He pronounced BACK in a short and clear manner, exactly as a Dutchman or German would say BEK. There was no hint of an "a" sound.

Comment: @M.Wind No, [he does not](https://youtu.be/l6Kf7I83Eq4?t=37). Germans and Dutchmen often can’t distinguish English /æ/ and /ɛ/ phonemes, thus confusing  ᴍᴀɴʏ minimal pairs that rely on those being critically different: *men/man gem/jam fen/fan Ted/tad met/mat Bess/bass bed/bad bet/bat Ken/can left/laughed send/sand lend/land fête/fat pet/pat Brett/brat Tex/tax pen/pan bend/band fed/fad med/mad net/gnat beg/bag blend/bland pest/past mesh/mash ex/axe less/lass den/Dan Ben/ban egg/Ag hem/ham heck/hack vet/vat* &c&c&c. **Just because Germans can hear no difference does ɴᴏᴛ mean it isn’t there!**